# PHP call an async nodejs script voa shell_exec

Tags: php, node.js, async-await, shell-exec

I have a nodejs script with an async method  (puppeteer chrome), when I run my script through the command line, everything works as expected.

When I try to run the same script via PHP, it is not working.
Here is an example

```
shell_exec("node /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/puppeteer_2/examples/test.js --param1=\"a1\" --param2=\"a3\" --param3=\"a3\" >/dev/null 2>&1");
```

Important note I don't need a return from the call.
And I also tried with the full path for node

In nodejs my code is wrapped inside this

```
(async() => {

//code

})();
```

Another note, if I do a `console.log` outside the async, then I have an output and I know at least it worked.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: And no output when logging from inside the async call?

Comment: No, no output so far

Comment: I had to give up the returned data.